# Linux Kernel Text Symbols

Tags: gdb, linux-kernel

When I look through a linux kernel OOPS output, the EIP and other code address have values in the range of 0xC01-----. In my System.map and `objdump -S vmlinux` output, all the code addresses are at least above 0xC1------. My vmlinux has debug symbols included (CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO).

When I debug over a serial connection (kgdb), and I load gdb with `gdb ./vmlinux`, again I have the same issue that I cannot reconcile $eip with what I have in System.map and `objdump` output. When I run `where` in gdb, I get a jumbled mess on the stack:

```
#0 0xC01----- in ?? ()
#1 0xC01----- in ?? ()
#2 0xC01----- in ?? ()
...
```

Can anyone make any suggestions on how to resolve this/these issues? My main concern is how I actually map an eip value from an OOPS to System.map or `objdump -S vmlinux`. I know that the OOPS will give me the function name and offset into the object code, but I am more concerned about the previously mentioned issue and why gdb can't correctly display a stack backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the OOPS is because you jumped into a place that's not a function.
This would easily cause a crash, and would also prevent the debugger from resolving the address as a symbol.

You can check this by disassembling the area around this EIP. If I'm correct, it won't make sense as machine code.

There are generally two causes for such things:
1. Function call using a corrupt function pointer. In this case, the stack frame before the last should show the caller. But you don't have this frame, so it may be the other reason.
2. Stack overrun - your return address is corrupt, so you've returned to a bad location. If it's so, the data ESP points to should contain the address in EIP. Debugging stack overruns is hard, because the most important source of information is missing. You can try to print the stack in "raw" format (x/xa addr), and try to make sense of it.